# ElementTree SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)

Tags: python, libxml2, elementtree

I've searched extensively for the past few days and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.  I've written a script using Python 2.7.3 and ElementTree to parse an XML file and edit an attribute buried deep within the XML file.  The script works fine.  I had a meeting late last week with the customer who informed me the target platform will be CentOS.  I thought, no problem.  To test on the anticipated platform I created a CentOS VMWare client and much to my surprise my script crapped the bed, giving me the error message, "**SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)**"  In the course of my researching the nature of this error message I learned that CentOS 6.4 supports Python 2.6.6, which contains an older version of ElementTree that does not have support for searching for attributes [@attribute] syntax.
This customer won't upgrade Python on the platform, nor will they install additional libraries, so lxml is not an option for me.  My question is, can I somehow still access the buried attribute and edit it without the ElementTree support for the [@attribute] facilities?

Here's an example of the kind of XML I'm dealing with:

```
`

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<my-gui>
    <vehicles>
        <car vendor="Ford"/>
    </vehicles>
    <options>
        <line transmission='manual'/>
    </options>
    <title>Dealership</title>
    <choice id='manual' title="Dealership">
        <pkg-deal id='manual' auth='manager'>.</pkg-deal>
    </choice>
    <choice id='manual' title='Dealership'/>
    <choice id='manual' DealerLocation='Dealer_Loc'/>
    <choices-outline color='color_choice'>
        <line choice='blue'/>
    </choices-outline>
    <choice id='cars' GroupID='convertables'>
        <pkg-deal id='model.Taurus' version="SEL" arguments='LeatherInterior' enabled='XMRadio'>Taurus</pkg-deal>
        <pkg-deal id='model.Mustang' version="GT" enabled='SIRIUSRadio'>Mustang</pkg-deal>
        <pkg-deal id='model.Focus' version="SE" enabled='XMRadio'>Focus</pkg-deal>
        <pkg-deal id='model.Fairlane'>Fairlane</pkg-deal>
        <pkg-deal id='model.Fusion' version="SE" arguments='ClothInerior'>Fusion</pkg-deal>
        <pkg-deal id='model.Fiesta' version="S Hatch" enabled="SIRIUSRadio">Fiesta</pkg-deal>
    </choice>
</my-gui>

`
```

Here's a snippet of the successful Python 2.7.3 code that breaks under Python 2.6.6:

```
if self.root.iterfind('pkg-deal'): 
          self.deal = self.root.find('.//pkg-deal[@id="model.fusion"]')
          self.arg = str(self.deal.get('arguments'))
          if self.arg.find('with Scotchguard=') > 0:  
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'DealerAssist', 'The selected car is already updated. Nothing to do.')            
            self.leave()        
          self.deal.set('arguments', self.arg + ' with Scotchguard') 
          ...
      ...
```

Is there a way I can modify the first line of this 'if' statement block that will allow me to edit the 'arguments' attribute of the Fusion element?  Or am I relegated to implementing libxml2, which promises to be a real pain?...

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this counts as installing additional libraries (and this is sort of side-stepping your question), but perhaps you could try copy-and-pasting the version of [ElementTree from Python 2.7](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py) into your script, and renaming the file to something like `ElementTree2.py` and just using that?

Comment: @Michael0x2a - wow! I hadn't thought of that.  That's very creative and might just work.  I think I may be able to include it as a separate file and import it.  I'm going to play with that and let you know.

Comment: @Michael0x2a - I tried copying ElementTree.py, renaming it ElementTree2.py and importing it, but kept getting invalid import errors.  Good thought though.

Comment: Huh. I guess I should have tried my suggestion out first :). It looks like ElementTree isn't meant to be a standalone file. What I ended up doing was going to the `Lib\xml` folder in `C:\Python27`, and copied the entire `etree` folder which ElementTree comes from (and renaming `etree` to `etree2`). Doing `import etree2.ElementTree` then appeared to work, although I didn't thoroughly test everything to make sure there were no more issues. (In particular, I'd rename and tweak all the files inside the `etree` folder to make sure there are no conflicts with the standard library)

Comment: @Michael0x2a - Thanks for the follow-up.  I've give that a try later this morning and report back.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @Michael0x2a - It worked like a champ!  I'm meeting with the customer later this afternoon and will ask them if this approach is acceptable to them.  Post your solution as and answer and I'll vote it up.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be side-stepping the question, but you could just try copying-and-pasting the version of ElementTree from Python 2.7, renaming it to avoid conflicting with the standard library, and importing and using that.

However, since ElementTree isn't meant to be used as a standalone file, what you need to do is navigate to `C:\Python27\Lib\xml` and copy the entire `etree` folder and import ElementTree by doing `import etree.ElementTree` inside your script.

To avoid accidentally importing or using the version of ElementTree from Python 2.6, you should probably rename the `etree` folder, its contents, delete the `.pyc` files, and fix the imports inside the file to reference the Python 2.7 version.

Answer (score 0):

This same problem was solved by another user [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667979/python-2-6-1-expected-path-separator)

This user filtered the attribute manually in Python 2.6. I'm posting their code example here even though the example pertains specifically to the asker's code:

```
def final_xml(self,username):
    users = self.root.findall("user")
    for user in users:
        if user.attrib.get('username') == 'user1':
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError('No such user')

    # `user` is now set to the correct element
    self.root.remove(user)
    print user
    tree = ET.ElementTree(self.root)
    tree.write("msl.xml")
```