# Problems with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I have a Debian 6 setup that I won't touch too much.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
$ dpkg --list|grep lxml
ii  python-lxml                        2.2.8-2
```

Im trying to access with XPath like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse("a.xml")

for e in root.findall('.//rec/data/field[@name="id"]'):
    print(e.tag + " " + e.attrib.get('name'))
```

I got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 4, in <module>
    for e in root.findall('.//rec/data/field[@name="id"]'):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 647, in findall
    return self._root.findall(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 355, in findall
    return ElementPath.findall(self, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 198, in findall
    return _compile(path).findall(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 176, in _compile
    p = Path(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 93, in __init__
    "expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)
SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)
```

Is this XPath syntax not supported by python-lxml 2.2.8 ?

What version support this and is compatible with python 2.6 ?

Comment: Your title is about lxml but your code use xml. Also you code works in Python 2.7 Not sure whether it's a Python 2.6 only issue.

Comment: Confirmed. ElementTree in python 2.6 does not support searching for attributes [@attribute] syntax. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753714/elementtree-syntaxerror-expected-path-separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is using [`ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), not `lxml`.

`findall` method of `ElementTree` supports only subset of xpath. ([XPath support in ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm)).

`[@attrib="value"]` is also supported in ElementTree API 1.3. **But** ElementTree API is updated to 1.3 in Python *2.7*.

---

Replace following line:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

with:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
```

to use `lxml`.