# Parsing xml using import minidom with if conditions

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

```
 <Game:quit>

           <Game:AnimalSet AnimalSet="Name" />
           <Game:Value Value="Lion" />

       </Game:quit>
       <Game:quit>

           <Game:AnimalSet AnimalSet="Name" />
           <Game:Value Value="Tiger" />

       </Game:quit>
       <Game:quit>

           <Game:AnimalSet AnimalSet="Name" />
           <Game:Value Value="Leopard" />

       </Game:quit>
       <Game:quit>

           <Game:DimensionSet AnimalSet="Name" />
           <Game:Value Value="Elephant" />

       </Game:quit>

   <Game:quit>

          <Game:AnimalSet AnimalSet="Place" />
          <Game:Value Value="USA" />
```

This is the chunk of xml from my sample.xml that I am mainly concerned of. I want to parse this xml in such a way using the from xml.dom import minidom import library, that I run if conditions and if the AnimalSet value is "Name" it will store/append its values which are "Lion", "Tiger", "Leopard" and "elephant" in some list. elif if the AnimalSet is "Place", it should store/append "USA" into another list.

I am stuck at the code at the beginning only, so would really appreciate if someone helps me starting on it.

Any help? Please raise questions if still anything is not clear. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to transform your xml into another xml?  Or extract data into a local data structure?

Comment: You are alternating namespaces between `Game` and `game`, this indicates completely different namespaces. Also, Stackoverflow works better when you ask *specific* questions. You are having trouble, because you have *no code*. Start small, writing code to open the XML file, then to print specific parts of specific nodes, then try and branch on the nodes.

Comment: I am trying to extract data into another python data structures, specifically lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a mission for XPath, so as an alternative to minidom, you may use ElementTree, whose `findall` method can find all elements with a `Value` attribute.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc = ET.parse(path_to_xml_file)
values = doc.findall('.//*[@Value]')
print [value.get('Value') for value in values]
```

For Python 2.6.6, ElementTree is unable to look for attributes, so you must use something else. There must be a `xmlns:Game` pseudo-attribute at the beginning of the file; copy its value in a `xmlns` variable, and try the following.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlns =  # the value of xmlns:Game
doc = ET.parse(path)
values = doc.findall('.//Game:Value', namespaces={'Game': xmlns})
print [value.get('Value') for value in values]
```

Comment: Giving me this error "expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)
SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)

at line 4.

Comment: This works with Python 2.7.6. Which version do you use ?

Comment: According to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753714/elementtree-syntaxerror-expected-path-separator), Python 2.6 gives the same error message.

Comment: Im using 2.6.6. Is there any way of doing in this version?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a solution that is more likely to work with Python 2.6.

Comment: what is this variable xmlns declared for?I didnt get that. I dont know with what to initialise this variable

Comment: `xmlns` holds the namespace URI. All tag names start with "Game:", so prefix "Game:" must be declared with something like `xmlns:Game="TheGame"`, usually at the beginning of the file. Look for this declaration in the XML file, and copy its value in the variable with `xmlns = 'TheGame'`.