# Error getting Python script to run on older version

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I had tested a web based application which uses Python (2.7.8) scripts to create a dynamic content.

I am parsing some XML data and performing several operations on it.

One of the operations requires searching certain type of data which uses the `findall(xpath)` function from `ElementTree`.

Now the place where I need to deploy is a Linux box which has an older version of Python (2.6.6).

I had some trouble due to the older `ElementTree` not having certain capabilities.

I followed this [ElementTree SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753714/elementtree-syntaxerror-expected-path-separator). I copied the `ElementTree` from 2.7.8 to the new box and imported from there.

It imports fine but now I get a different error which is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./filename_python.py", line 117, in <module>
    for ch in child.findall(xpath):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 293, in findall
    return list(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 194, in select
    if "".join(e.itertext()) == value:
AttributeError: itertext
```

I cannot update the Python version on that box and I cannot add any modules so anything new has to be imported locally.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to me that you've backported the 2.7.x version library properly. Take a look at the stack trace and you will see it is still referring to the library in your Python 2.6.x path:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py
```

You could also consider lxml - you don't need to install it as a system library. Simply clone from the [git repository here](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/), and copy the code into your projects directory.

Comment: Do i need to change my initial code to work with or is it as simple as from lxml.etree import ElementTree ?

Also I should mention that I'm using cElementTree instead of ElementTree for a faster implementation.

And is there anyway I could properly backport the library instead of using lxml?

Comment: lxml is not compatible, so yes you would need to change your code. If that's not a good solution for you, take a look into why the wrong ElementPath.py is being used (you are not using the 2.7 version you imported locally).